# How to use the result of prepared statement in 'if not exists' clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I have a stored procedure with prepared statement and i would like to know how to use the result of that statement in 'if not exists' clause.

The example of the procedure is shown below.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS PSCheck;

DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE PSCheck(IN TableName tinytext, IN ColumnName tinytext)
begin
    SET @sc=CONCAT("show columns from ",TableName," like '",ColumnName,"'");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sc;
    EXECUTE stmt;    

    IF NOT EXISTS (        
        SELECT @sc        
        )    
    THEN
        SELECT 'OK';
    END IF;

  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
end;
;;

DELIMITER ;

CALL PSCheck('tbl', 'col');
```

'THEN' block never executes regardless of existance of the field.

Comment: The variable exists, you're selecting the variable and returning that.

Comment: i would suggest rewritting to use infromation_schema.COLUMNS so you can use COUNT(*) and directy load 0 or 1 into a MySQL user variable.. `SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @exists FROM ... ` then you can use the `IF ... THEN ...  END IF` more easy

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: To Raymond Nijland: AFAIK in order to use  infromation_schema I need root access to DB, but I don't have such rights.

Comment: To Gordon Linoff: Actually, I want to add a column to the table if that column doesn't exist. I can't use infromation_schema. So, I try find if that column exists in table using 'show column ...' SQL query.

Comment: To Grenther: Well, thanks. But then how can I use the prepared statement result in 'if not exists'?

Answer (score 0):

You can significantly simplify the logic:

```
create procedure PSCheck (
    in in_TableName tinytext,
    in in_ColumnName tinytext
)
begin    
    if exists (select 1 from information_schema.columns where table_name = in_tablename and column_name = in_columnname) then
        select 'OK';
    end if;
end;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2e024185d8cc76b04659ea61081ff39f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: AFAIK in order to use infromation_schema I need root access to DB, but I don't have such rights.

Comment: @cppdev . . . I would be surprised if I had root access to "db<>fiddle".  I am not aware of such a requirement.

Comment: Well, on my system I don't have access to it at all. Talking of prep. statement do you know how to do what I've asked?